# Using an XSL to reformat datetime in SOAP Message but getting errors

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

I am very new to XSL and SOAP messages so please be kind. I'm trying to create a XSL to reformat a few elements in a SOAP message but I'm having no luck succeeding. The general error I'm getting is Cannot transform: Extra Content at the end of the document. I've been trying to read what that means and it's not making as much sense to me. If anyone can help onto what I'm doing wrong I'd be forever grateful!

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soapenv:Body>
<Get__CompIntfc__VNDR_IDResponse xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Enterprise/Tools/schemas/M5540000.V1">
<SETID>SKSK</SETID>
<CREATED_DTTM>1900-01-01T00.00.00.000000</CREATED_DTTM>
</Get__CompIntfc__VNDR_IDResponse>
</soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

here is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:m="http://www.example.org/stock" version="1.0">

  <xsl:template match="//soapenv:body/m:Get__CompIntfc__VNDR_IDResponse/*">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CREATED_DTTM">
     <xsl:element name="CREATED_DTTM">
         <xsl:call-template name="formatdate">
             <xsl:with-param name="datestr" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="formatdate">
     <xsl:param name="datestr"/>
    <xsl:variable name="date">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,1,13)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="mm">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,15,2)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="ss">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,18,2)"/>
    </xsl:variable>

     <xsl:variable name="msec">
       <xsl:value-of select="substring($datestr,21,6)"/>
    </xsl:variable>



    <xsl:value-of select="$date"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="':'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$mm"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="':'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$ss"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="':'"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="$msec"/>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="node()|@*"> 
     <xsl:copy> 
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The code you have posted does not produce the error you cite. It does however have a problem of mismatched namespaces. As a result, your date-formatting template is not called.

Comment: You're going to an awful lot of trouble to just convert periods ('.') to colons (':').  If that's what you want to do, and *all* you want to do, then you can replace your whole `formatdate` template with one call to the standard `translate()` function.

Comment: Note also that a valid ISO 8601 time format requires either a dot or a comma to separate between seconds and decimal fractions of a second. If you want your output to conform to the XML Schema specification, then only the decimal point is allowed.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I still get a little confused with namespaces. @michael.hor257k Would you be able to give me a little incite on how my namespaces are mismatched?

Comment: you're also correct, i need to have a dot in between the seconds and milliseconds. i'll change that in my code.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the exact output you expect to get as the result of transforming the given input.